# Looking for a more efficient way to add my repositories in startup.cs and controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Im working with Entity Framework Repository pattern and I have a lot of repositories. Right now, for each repository I add them in the startup.cs as follows:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
```

To use the repository, I add it into the controller as follows:

```
private readonly IRepository _repository;

public Controller(IRepository repository){
    _repository = repository;
}
```

As you can imagine, because I have a lot of repositories these lists will become very long. It doesn't look nice. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Generic repository pattern or otherwise defining your repository per entity then you are likely encountering one of the reasons I consider the generic repository pattern an anti-pattern when working with EF.

If you are not employing unit testing /w a mocking structure for dependencies then repositories become largely redundant as opposed to just leveraging the DbContext(s) as injected dependencies.

For example, if I have a CreateOrderController, and the process of creating an order I need information about a Customer, Address details, Products, Orders, Suppliers, etc. Using generic repositories I essentially end up with:

```
public CreateOrderController(IOrderRepository orderRepository, ICustomerRepository customerRepository, IProductRepository productRepository, ISupplierRepository supplierRepository, IAddressRepository addressRepository) // etc.
```

If this is the nightmare you see yourself facing, there is an alternative. The pattern I find quite a lot easier to manage is to define repositories scoped to a controller or service. That repository is responsible for all data layer requirements for that controller/service.

If I instead manage all entities relevant to creating an order in one repository, that constructor becomes:

```
public CreateOrderController(ICreateOrderRepository createOrderRepository)
```

CreateOrderRepository will have methods to retrieve orders, customers, products, suppliers, etc. suitable to what the Create Order process requires.

The typical counter-argument to this approach is that it is violating DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) since several controllers will inevitably want to retrieve customers or products etc. so methods like GetProducts() would appear in multiple places.

It is a trade-off for simplicity, as well as avoiding violating SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) which IMHO is a more important principle to adhere to than DRY. The trouble with generic repositories is while they look like they serve a single responsibility, I.e. all things to do with Product; They end up either adhering to SRP in an increasingly inefficient or complex way, or they violate SRP as any given method to retrieve or otherwise work with the domain serves multiple concerns and as a result has many reasons to change.

Given a situation where we have a GetCustomer() method in a CustomerRepository that is called by 3+ different controllers, giving it 3 reasons to change. Some controllers need related data, some controllers just need a subset of data, etc. The moment you face a situation where one controller needs are a bit different you're faced with a decision:

- Everything standardizes on the lowest common denominator (adhering to DRY) leaving some consumers with a less efficient than they could have. (I.e. getting all fields or related data even if they don't need it)
- Introduce complexity to try and satisfy everyone's distinct needs, increasing the testing load as complexity gives bugs places to hide. (I.e. passing expressions or magic strings for filtering, sorting, eager loading, then more settings for pagination) [This is a favourite I see when devs want to introduce repositories to "abstract away" the fact they are using EF... Which is not a very convincing reason to use repositories.]
- Introduce several separate distinct methods that do things similar to one another to serve the specific needs of each distinct consumer. (violating DRY, and creating a maintenance nightmare remembering which flavour of GetCustomer()-like method suits a specific need and a reuse nightmare)

A GetCustomer() method in the CreateOrderRepository has one, and only one reason to change. It is only as complex as what the Create Order process requires, making it much simpler overall, and can be tuned without concerns for other dependants.

So to summarize: Two ideas to consider... Don't bother with repositories and use the DbContext(s), or consolidate the repositories so one is designated to serve the needs of their controller / service.